# Using Microsoft graph API to access O365 Myapps

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

I'm trying to get all of the apps that are available through my apps with the graph API and I don't see any call that allows me to do that.

I've been reading their documentation here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/office365/api/api-catalog however, have been unable to find anything that pertains to my issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation you are referring to is actually for the Office 365 API. The Graph API is available here: http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs . While the two are similar in functionality, it is recommended to use Graph to access O365 data moving forward, as it is a unified endpoint for this and other services.

To find a user's available apps, you can get the "assignedPlans" property of a user. The call to the Graph would be:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[uid]/assignedPlans
```

where UID is the user's ID or email address.

Comment: Thank you! Is there any way to also get the apps that we've added through azure as a proxy application or web application using the Graph API? It's only giving me default the Microsoft ones.

Comment: The applications endpoint will show you all the applications enabled for your org: 

```https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/applications```

This query uses the beta endpoint.

You can read about other information you can access about applications [here](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/beta/resources/application)

Comment: That works! one more quick question. Is there a way to get only the application that each user has enabled for them? Instead of grabbing all of the applications?

Comment: I think what you are looking for is:
```https://graph.microsoft.com/beta/users/[uid]/appRoleAssignments```

Comment: I'm getting Unsupported Segment Type when trying this out? I can't seem to get any appRole calls working.

Comment: Thanks for bringing this to my attention. I have filed a bug against the documentation so that we can get some clarification on what's going wrong! I'm seeing the same issue as you are.
https://github.com/OfficeDev/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/441