# How to get O365 applications using Microsoft Graph API?

Tags: office365, microsoft-graph-api

With an Office 365 subscription you are able to use O365 applications, depending on your license, as Word, Excel, etc.
Apart you have Azure AD applications. These links show you a merged list of the applications of AzureAD and O365.

https://www.office.com/apps?auth=2&home=1
https://account.activedirectory.windowsazure.com/r#/applications

With Graph I am able to get AzureAD ones:
https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/application?view=graph-rest-beta

But I can't find a way to get O365 applications detailed information.

Following [Using Microsoft graph API to access O365 Myapps](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39104083/using-microsoft-graph-api-to-access-o365-myapps)

I tried to get the pplications from:

https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/[uid]/assignedPlans

But this only gives information about the servicePlan not the application info like "launchUri".

What I am trying to do is build a page similar to the ones provided.

Comment: I'm not sure if that's possible. Can't you compose the URI yourself? They are pretty straight forward like https://www.office.com/launch/excel?auth=2&username=user@domain.com

Comment: Thanks for your reply. For excel and word seems quite simple but it does not follow an standard eg: https://www.office.com/launch/word?auth=2&username= but for other O365 like OneDrive is: https://XYZ.my.sharepoint.com/_layouts/15/MySite.aspx?MySiteRedirect=

Comment: For OneDrive you can use this one for everyone https://<tenantname>-my.sharepoint.com/. You only have to change the tenantname